# Could anyone please show me how to correctly use GDAL Grid in Python?

Tags: python, gis, gdal, geo

I am trying to create a group of contour polygons from a set of scatter points containing numeric data of some sorts, for example temperature.
The method I used to apply is to generate a raster through spatial interpolation then perform contour then construct polygons with these contour lines or convert raster cells to polygons. All these were done in ArcGIS.
But considering the expiration of license, I want to do the same thing in plain python. I tried PostGIS but it did not work out. Now I turn to GDAL.

My plan is to create a smooth surface geotiff file from points with gdal.Grid, then use gdal.ContourGenerate to get contour lines, and finally construct polygons with these contour lines and some mask line rings such as a border. However I am stuck at the very first step.

This is my code, the script only creates empty geotiff file, the documentation of GDAL does not really tell much on this function. Could anyone help me solve this?

the input test.shp is a ESRI shapefile, it has a column named 'value' which stores the data I want to use for interpolation.

```
import gdal

option = gdal.GridOptions(format='GTiff',
                      width=250,height=250,
                      algorithm='invdist:power=2',
                      layers=['d:/work/contour/test.shp'],
                      zfield='value')

out = gdal.Grid('d:/work/contour/test.tif',
                    'd:/work/contour/test.shp',
                    options=option)

out.FlushCache()
out = None
del out
```

Comment: The function gdal.RasterizeLayer works fine, but it does not give estimated values at places where there is no input data.

Comment: what's the problem with the code you provided?